# Excepted behavior for overlapping dstdomains entries in Squid 4.1

Tags: squid

Per [documentation](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/acl/), if using dstdomain and having overlapping entries in the list, Squid should generate a warning message.   For example I have this in my `/etc/squid/squid.conf`:

```
acl dst_domains dstdomain "/etc/squid/dst_domains.txt"
http_access allow localnet dst_domains
```

And `/etc/squid/dst_domains.txt` contains an overlap, like this:

```
.googlecloud.com
.updates.googlecloud.com
test.updates.googlecloud.com
```

Will indeed result in a warning message in `/var/log/squid/cache.log`:

```
2023/09/08 19:31:21 kid1| WARNING: '.updates.googlecloud.com' is a subdomain of '.googlecloud.com'
2023/09/08 19:31:21 kid1| WARNING: You should remove '.updates.googlecloud.com' from the ACL named 'dst_domains'
2023/09/08 19:31:21 kid1| WARNING: 'test.updates.googlecloud.com' is a subdomain of '.googlecloud.com'
2023/09/08 19:31:21 kid1| WARNING: You should remove 'test.updates.googlecloud.com' from the ACL named 'dst_domains'
```

But here's a similar overlap:

```
us-docker.pkg.dev
.pkg.dev
```

Which instead triggers an error and causes squid to Terminate:

```
2023/09/08 19:47:47 kid1| ERROR: 'us-docker.pkg.dev' is a subdomain of '.pkg.dev'
2023/09/08 19:47:47 kid1| ERROR: You need to remove 'us-docker.pkg.dev' from the ACL named 'dst_domains'
2023/09/08 19:47:47 kid1| storeDirWriteCleanLogs: Starting...
2023/09/08 19:47:47 kid1|   Finished.  Wrote 0 entries.
2023/09/08 19:47:47 kid1|   Took 0.03 seconds (  0.00 entries/sec).
2023/09/08 19:47:47 kid1| FATAL: Bungled /etc/squid/squid.conf line 57: acl dst_domains dstdomain "/etc/squid/dst_domains.txt"
2023/09/08 19:47:47 kid1| Squid Cache (Version 4.13): Terminated abnormally.
```

Can anyone explain this behavior?  Really seems like a more specific overlap over the general triggers warning, but specific followed by generate triggers error.

Answer (score 0):

Found my [answer](https://lists.squid-cache.org/pipermail/squid-users/2015-August/004937.html); so yes this is expected (but undesirable) behavior: